npm link overwrites packages with same @ handle
Lets assume I create two packages (pk1) and pkg2) that are somehow dependent and share the same @ handle for the name field of the package.json.
A minimal example for pkg1 might look like this:
{
  "name": "@test/pkg1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My package",
  "author": "",
}

For pkg2 the name is redefined as @test/pkg2
After navigating to each folder and using npm link, the global list of packages will look like this:
C:\Program Files\nodejs -> .\
+-- @test/pkg1@1.0.0 -> [...]
+-- @test/pkg2@1.0.0 -> [...]

When navigating to the project and typing npm link @test/pkg1 and npm link @test/pkg2 I would expect to see the following new folders
node_modules\@test\pk1 and node_modules\@test\pk2. Instead, the folders are replaced/overwritten with the last executed command, so there is only one subfolder under @test.
Is this the expected behavior? If so, what is the correct way to "group" packages that belong to the same project/institution?
